# Javascript/HTML, writing a variable in a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

So it looks like this:

```
var taps = "";

if (temp >= 20)
    taps = "tapsAff";
else
    taps = "tapsOan";
```

Now the tricky bit drawing taps in a div tag?

using something like this `<div id="xyear" style="width: 320px; position: absolute; top: 152px; left: 2px; z-index: 1;"> do i put taps here? </div>` but that will only write "do i put taps here?"

Also if its any help what im trying to achieve is this http://www.taps-aff.co.uk/

Comment: If you have zero experience in a language, the solution is to learn at least the basics of the language by reading a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: The [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) page will provide you links to all the resources you need to get started.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript write: (this will overwrite the text already in `xyear`)

```
document.getElementById("xyear").innerHTML = taps;
```

if you want the value of `taps` to add on to what you already have you could write:

```
document.getElementById("xyear").innerHTML += taps;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your div :

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

And your JavaScript :

```
var taps = "taps";
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = taps;
```

`getElementById` search an id in your html page. In your case use `xyear` as id.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4C2B/)